# Grab number left and right of string using PHP for MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database table column that has a size value in multiple formats where users manually entered different value formats.

Using PHP I need to iterate DB table and process this field to grab a withd and height value from each column when the column value matches into the pattern we create...

Below are 90% of the values in these formats.  Many are the same format but with either single or double digit to left or right side of lowercase or capital `X`

Usung PHP how could I match each string to strip all non numeric characters from the value on the left and right side of the X.

left = width
right side = height

```
1x1
1X1
1"x1"

12x12
12X12
12"x12"
12"X12"

NULL
'' ,_ empty field
```

I just need to get these values into a width and height variable in PHP.

If I can grab everything left of lowercase and capital X ad well as right of and strip all non numbers then I think it would work easily

---

There are other values as well and those one should be ignored as they will not fit the pattern.  Below is example of some of those odd values I found so far...

```
18" channel letters

64x20 x 2

Glass Dimensions: 12"x72"

172.61 cm x 28.46 cm
230.15 cm x 42.07 cm
24x24 Interior Double Sided
```

These type of values should be ignored so I can manually edit these later

Comment: So you just want to get the to values to the right and left of the X ?

Comment: @Rizier123 yes, keeping in mind case of x should not matter.  Also if it sees a value like this `172.61 cm x 28.46 cm` I would rather it skip over it instead of tunring it into `17261` and `2846`

Comment: And what do you want to do if the value is like: `NULL`, where there are no numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written up a function called `rough_strip_all` that should strip all characters in a string except for those listed. Adding this step *may* resolve the issue for you, but if it doesn't, you might have to look into recompiling to enable the UTF8 support for PCRE.

```
<?php

// Strips out all characters except for those in allowed set
function rough_strip_all( $string, $allowed_set = '0123456789x. ' )
{
    // Takes the allowed set, splits it into character by character,
    // then converts each character in the array to its ASCII value
    $allowed_ascii = array_map( function($a) {
        return ord( $a );
    }, str_split( $allowed_set ) );

    $return = '';
    for( $i = 0, $ilen = mb_strlen( $string ); $i < $ilen; $i++ )
    {
        // Check if the ASCII value of current character is in the list of allowed
        // ascii characters given. If it is, add it to the return string
        $ascii = ord( $string{$i} );
        if( in_array( $ascii, $allowed_ascii ) )
        {
            $return .= $string{$i};
        }
    }

    // Returns the newly compiled string
    return $return;
}

// Original string
$string = "Misc text: 35.25”x 21.00” 123 extra text 456";

// Display original string
echo "Original string: {$string}<br />";

// Strips out all characters except the following: '0123456789x. '
$string = rough_strip_all( strtolower( $string ) );

// Strip out all characters except for numbers, letter x, decimal points, and spaces
$string = preg_replace( '/([^0-9x \.])/ui', '', $string );

// Find anything that fits the number X number format (including decimal numbers)
preg_match( '/([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?) ?x ?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)/ui', $string, $values );

// Match found
if( !empty( $values ) )
{
    // Set dimensions in easy to read variables
    $dimension_a = $values[1];
    $dimension_b = $values[3];

    // Values returned
    echo "Dimension A: {$dimension_a}<br />";
    echo "Dimension B: {$dimension_b}<br />";
}
// No match found
else
{
    echo "No match found.";
}

?>
```

This should should also work for the additional outliers you added in as it strips out all non-essential characters first, then attempts to make a match. I've also added some display logic to it so you can see the original string and what each dimension is after its been processed, or a message if there has been no match.

Comment: Thanks this works pretty good until I run into a value that had this weird backwards quote like character... `35”x21”` it has `”` instead of `"` can your code be modified to detect and remove this character?

Comment: I will just run this before your code runs on it `$string = str_replace('”','"',$string);`

Comment: Strangly that backwards thing and this `*` are not sripped and even ahlt my app to a stop in this example http://codepad.org/PEQYUb0C - I see it shows the errors now `Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: this version of PCRE is not compiled with PCRE_UTF8 support at offset 1683977065 on line 21` any ideas how to get around bad characters like that?

Comment: The only way I can think of right now are really hacky ways to get around it, and I can't get to a machine with PHP for at least a few more hours to test a few things out. I'm presuming you don't have access to recompile anything on the server to enable the UTF8 support?

Comment: @JasonDavis Alright, I've come up with a function that _may_ help resolve your issue. I've edited my answer to include the new functionality. Try that out and see how you go.

Answer (score 0):

Even easier would be `preg_match_all("/[0-9]+/", $string, $matches);`

Test cases:

> 1x1
>   1\"x1
>   12X12
>   Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 >[1] => 1 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 12 [1] => 12 ) )